# MutableLiveData retains old value even when the observer activity gets destroyed

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-mvvm, mutablelivedata

I have an activity which is observing livedata from repository. Now when the activity gets destroyed and then created again, i still get the old value from repository unless i fetch the new one manually.

Why is the mutablelivedata retaining its old value even after the observer activity is destroyed?

Comment: Do you use Dagger or Koin to inject ViewModel into activity? Or do you custom ViewModelFactory?

Comment: I am using viewmodelproviders

Comment: Please show code in your activity and repository where you get livedata

Comment: I was initializing MutableLiveData variables before instantiating the viewmodel. Now i initialise the variables in the viewmodel constructor and the problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

you can reduce lifetime of your ViewModel, in this case newly created ViewModel won't persist previous data.

Alternatively, you can manually call inside your activity

```
override fun onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy()
    viewModel.clear()
}
```

inside viewmodel:

```
fun clear(){ myLiveData.value = defaultValue /*or null*/ }
```

or change MutableLiveData with LiveEvent
https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8

Comment: Yes currently i am clearing the viewmodel just like you suggested. But i think the livedata should clear itself when the activity gets destroyed. There should be a proper way to do this maybe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SingleLiveData<T>` observer.

```
class SingleLiveData<T> : MutableLiveData<T?>() {

    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T?>) {
        super.observe(owner, Observer { t ->
            if (t != null) {
                observer.onChanged(t)
                postValue(null)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now an instance of `MutableLiveData<T>` you can use `SingleLiveData<T>`. It will call only one time.

```
private val data = SingleLiveData<String>()
```

Comment: This solved my problem , should be an accepted answer.